# Looping through results of 2 queries

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 queries that show month to date totals. I need to loop through them so they end up in the same table. Is it possible to combine the WHILE or combine the queries to have the ORDERS alternate?

```
$MTDcurrent = $db->Execute("SELECT SUM(order_total) AS MTDC, month(date_purchased) AS Months FROM " . TABLE_ORDERS ." 
                        WHERE orders_status IN(1,2,3,100,101,103,105) AND date(date_purchased) BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(current_date,'%Y-01-01') AND current_date GROUP BY Months ASC LIMIT 10 ");

$MTDprevious = $db->Execute("SELECT SUM(order_total) AS MTDP, month(date_purchased) AS Months FROM " . TABLE_ORDERS ." 
                        WHERE orders_status IN(1,2,3,100,101,103,105) AND date(date_purchased) BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 1 year),'%Y-01-01') AND date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 1 year)
                        GROUP BY Months ASC LIMIT 10 ");
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a slightly different approach avoiding the multiple queries.  I have not tried it as I do not have an RDBMS on the machine I am using right now but it should be close enough -

```
SELECT
    SUM(order_total) AS MTDP,
    month(date_purchased) AS Months,
    year(date_purchased) AS Years
FROM orders
WHERE orders_status IN(1,2,3,100,101,103,105)
AND DATE(date_purchased) > DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 year),'%Y-01-01')
GROUP BY Years, Months
ORDER BY Months ASC, Years ASC
```

In your response to your comment - you could modify the date part of the WHERE clause to be a combination of your two WHERE clauses

```
AND (
        (date(date_purchased) BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(current_date,'%Y-01-01') AND current_date)
    OR
        (date(date_purchased) BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 1 year),'%Y-01-01') AND date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 1 year))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The only issue I have with this is that for the previous year it totals the entire month rather than .. since it's the 8th .. The first 8 days of february.

Comment: ROCK SOLID!! Thanks so much. Trying to figure out how to output the result by month in a row. I think I responded the wrong way before by editing. NOt sure how to respond with code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly with while loop like this:

```
while( ($row = array_shift( $MTDcurrent)) || ($row = array_shift( $MTDprevious))){
    $row = 'your data';
}
```

However I don't consider this clean and obvious way. You may rather merge arrays with [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) (if there's no large amount of data):

```
foreach( array_merge( $MTDcurrent, $MTDprevious) as $row){
   $row = 'your data';
}
```

And if your code is performance critical and will use large amount of data you should implement [`Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) with `next` function like this:

```
public function next() {
  $this->row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $this->query);
  if( $this->row){
     return;
  }

  if( count( $this->queries)){
    $this->query = mysql_query( array_shift( $this->queries));
    $this->next();
  }
}
```

*Warning: this is just an idea, not whole implementation you should rely on!*

**EDIT** blah, I got question wrong, you're looking for [mysql `UNION` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).